# How to include entities that have many-to-one relationship with entities that have many-to-one relationship with initial entity in C# with EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

**The relationships of my entities:**
Course records have a one-to-many relationship with Enrollment records. Enrollment records have a one-to-many relationship with Student records.

**My Problem:**
I would like to select a single Course entity and be able to access the Student entities associated to Enrollments associated to the Course. I would like to do this all in one single query, and I want the return type to be Courses. However, the code below throws an exception with the message "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

```
Courses course = db.Courses.Where(course => course.Id == courseId)
    .Include(course => course.Enrollments)
    .ThenInclude(enrollments => enrollments.Select(enrollment => enrollment.Student))
    .First();
```

**Some alterations I have tried:**

- I tried putting the Include and ThenInclude calls before the Where call to no avail.
- If I comment out the ThenInclude lines, then this line executes with no error (but without the needed data obviously)
- I tried refactoring everything in the ThenInclude into the Include, and I got the same runtime exception.
- I tried using SelectMany instead of Select, and I got the same error.

**My Question:**
Is there some way for me to use Include to select all entities of type a associated with any of the entities of type b that are associated with a given entity of type c?

**Preference:**
I am aware that I can grab all of this data using Select and not use Include at all, but I would like to use Include to do this, if possible.

**Other Info Relevant to my Problem:**
I am using EFCore 3.1.3 and Sql Server 2014.

Let me know if you need any further clarification. Thank you for reading this far :)

**P.S.** Please edit if you can think of a more concise title for this question.

Comment: You misunderstand the argument of the `ThenInclude` - it's always entity, not a collection. e.g. something simply like `.ThenInclude(enrollment => enrollment.Students)`